# How to make convert csv to fancy tables?

Tags: longtable, csv, csvsimple, fancytabs

I want convert csv to fancy tables like this :

[image: ioo]

First, I make a basic table with my MWE like this :

```
\documentclass{article}
%\usepackage{csvsimple}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable,filecontents}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.9}% supress warning

\begin{filecontents*}{test.csv}
Presentation,Views,Downloads,Favorites,Comments,Email Shares,Facebook Shares,Tweets,LinkedIn Shares 
Biber,3,0,0,0,0,0,0,0   
Matlab Prettifier Package,68,0,0,0,0,0,0,0  
LaTeX3,173,1,0,0,0,0,0,0    
PythonTeX,84,0,0,0,0,0,0,0  
PerlTeX,131,0,0,0,0,0,0,0   
Matplotlib ,37,0,0,0,0,0,0,0    
SciPy,68,0,1,0,0,0,0,0  
PythonTeX Quick Start,22,0,0,0,0,0,0,0  
Introduction to PythonTeX,34,0,0,0,0,0,0,0  
IPython,30,0,0,0,0,0,0,0    
Matplotlib Introduction ,30,0,0,0,0,0,0,0   
Galeri PythonTeX,54,0,0,0,0,0,0,0   
IPython : Operasi Dasar di Sympy,30,0,0,0,0,0,0,0   
Introduction to IPython ,22,1,0,0,0,0,0,0   
Introduction to NumPy,23,0,0,0,0,0,0,0  
Road to PythonTeX ,72,0,0,0,0,0,0,0 
PythonTeX dan Sympy kolaborasi ,28,3,0,0,0,0,0,0    
Andreas Linz Beamer ,33,0,0,0,0,0,0,0   
Menyisipkan teks Arab ke LaTeX,21,0,0,0,0,0,0,0 
Xelatex & Japanese,17,0,0,0,0,0,0,0 
Korean xelatex,27,0,0,0,0,0,0,0 
Wordlike,19,0,0,0,0,0,0,0   
LaTeX    Notasi Matematika ,68,10,0,0,0,0,0,0
MusicTEX " Simpony LATEX dalam Musik " ,255,0,0,0,0,0,0,0   
Membuat Dokumen LaTeX3,23,1,0,0,0,0,0,0 
Membuat Dokumen Beamer LaTeX,63,1,0,0,0,0,0,0   
Membuat Dokumen LaTeX ,146,4,0,0,0,0,0,0    
Beamer   Media Presentasi LaTeX,141,15,0,0,0,0,0,0
Membuat Dokumen LaTeX,273,5,0,0,0,0,3,0 
Beamer Theme Glugor,49,0,0,0,0,0,0,0    
Minted, High Lighting Source Code,68,0,0,0,0,0,0,0  
Penggunaan dua bahasa dalam dokumen LATEX,142,0,0,0,0,0,0,0 
Solusi kesalahan ketika penggantian bahasa,138,0,0,0,0,0,0,0    
Ping! LaTeX ,215,0,0,0,0,0,0,0  
Membuat Dokumen LaTeX edisi 13,313,6,0,0,0,0,0,0    
Beamer, Media Presentasi LaTeX,216,5,0,0,0,0,0,0    
Membuat dokumen la tex edisi 12,405,2,0,0,0,0,5,0   
Membuat Dokumen LaTeX  Eleventh Edition,454,18,2,0,0,0,0,0  
Presentasi Beamer : Dark Themes,228,0,0,0,0,0,0,0   
Simpleslides, Media Presentasi ConTeXt ,83,3,0,0,0,0,0,0    
Laporan Metode Statistikia II,236,0,0,0,0,0,0,0 
Con text Untuk Pemula,48,1,0,0,0,0,0,0  
My Talking Custom and Tools ,116,0,0,0,0,0,0,0  
Farm Frenzy ,299,1,0,0,0,0,0,0  
LaTeX 3 Paper,73,1,0,0,0,0,0,0  
R -Sweave/ Sweave For Statistical Programming at LaTeX ,165,5,0,0,0,0,0,0   
LaTeX Cheat Sheet,194,9,0,0,0,0,0,0 
LaTeX Cheat Sheet ,77,0,0,0,0,0,0,0 
PlainTeX, A Virgin TeX :),129,2,0,0,0,0,0,0 
Beamer atau .PpT,288,11,0,0,0,0,0,0 
Xelatex,142,5,0,0,0,0,0,0   
Powerdot slide,276,25,0,0,0,0,0,0   
Kaligrafi and math font,328,2,0,0,0,0,0,0   
Utopia regular with math design,225,1,0,0,0,0,0,0   
Tx fonts,195,1,0,0,0,0,0,0  
Times,203,1,0,0,0,0,0,0 
Px fonts,189,1,0,0,0,0,0,0  
Palatino,209,1,0,0,0,0,0,0  
New century school book,201,1,0,0,0,0,0,0   
Lx font,21,0,0,0,0,0,0,0    
Latin modern,25,0,0,0,0,0,0,0   
Kurier light condensed,24,0,0,0,0,0,0,0 
Kurier light,18,0,0,0,0,0,0,0   
Kurier condensed,13,0,0,0,0,0,0,0   
Kurier condensed,21,0,0,0,0,0,0,0   
Kurier,203,0,0,0,0,0,0,0    
Kurier,50,0,0,0,0,0,0,0 
Kerkis,42,0,0,0,0,0,0,0 
Kp sans serif,38,0,0,0,0,0,0,0  
Iwona light condensed,15,0,0,0,0,0,0,0  
Iwona light,16,0,0,0,0,0,0,0    
Iwona condensed,27,0,0,0,0,0,0,0    
Iwona,15,0,0,0,0,0,0,0  
Gfs neohellenic,19,0,0,0,0,0,0,0    
Gfs artemisia with,22,0,0,0,0,0,0,0 
Gfs artemisia,22,0,0,0,0,0,0,0  
Computer modern light,18,0,0,0,0,0,0,0  
Computer modern,12,0,0,0,0,0,0,0    
Computer concrete,16,0,0,0,0,0,0,0  
Charter bt,13,0,0,0,0,0,0,0 
Charter bt,20,0,0,0,0,0,0,0 
Boisik,21,0,0,0,0,0,0,0 
Arev,24,0,0,0,0,0,0,0   
Antykwa toruÅ„ska light,9,0,0,0,0,0,0,0 
Antykwa toruÅ„ska condensed light,18,0,0,0,0,0,0,0  
Antykwa toruÅ„ska condensed,16,0,0,0,0,0,0,0    
Antykwa toruÅ„ska,23,0,0,0,0,0,0,0  
Chap16 scr,158,3,0,0,0,0,0,0    
Chap15 scr,36,2,0,0,0,0,0,0 
Chap14 scr,56,1,0,0,0,0,0,0 
Chap12 scr,68,3,0,0,0,0,0,0 
Chap11 scr,53,2,0,0,0,0,0,0 
Chap10 scr,41,2,0,0,0,0,0,0 
Chap09 scr,240,1,0,0,0,0,0,0    
Chap08 scr,51,2,0,0,0,0,0,0 
Chap07 scr,56,1,0,0,0,0,0,0 
Chap06 scr,48,1,0,0,0,0,0,0 
Chap05 scr,36,1,0,0,0,0,0,0 
Chap04 scr,33,1,0,0,0,0,0,0 
Chap03 scr,56,1,0,0,0,0,0,0 
Chap02 scr,88,1,0,0,0,0,0,0 
Chap01 scr,401,2,0,0,0,0,0,0    
Chap17 scr,140,1,0,0,0,0,0,0    
Chap13 scr,66,4,0,0,0,0,0,0 
Fancy Beamer :),78,0,0,0,0,0,1,0    
Vector in ConTeXt ,55,0,0,0,0,0,1,0 
Synonyms in ConTeXt,47,0,0,0,0,0,1,0    
Special character in ConTeXt ,63,0,0,0,0,0,1,0  
Powerdot LaTeX,324,1,0,0,0,0,1,0    
Outlinde text in ConTeXt,49,0,0,0,0,0,1,0   
MetaPost in LaTeX,137,3,0,0,0,0,1,0 
Math in ConTeXt ,142,4,0,0,0,0,1,0  
Math basic in ConTeXt,124,1,0,0,0,0,1,0 
Math align in ConTeXt ,64,0,0,0,0,0,1,0 
Itemize in ConTeXt,459,0,0,0,0,0,1,0    
Definitions in ConTeXt,153,0,0,0,0,0,1,0    
Columns in  ConTeXt ,61,0,0,0,0,0,0,0   
Combining Statistical Programming with LaTeX,29,0,0,0,0,0,0,0   
Combining Statistical Programming with LaTeX,38,2,0,0,0,0,0,0   
Beamer Presentation,459,11,0,2,0,0,1,0  
Pengantar la tex,246,5,0,0,0,0,1,0  
LaTeX InDesign Creative Cloud with PGF/ TikZ,1512,24,0,0,0,0,1,0    
Post Script LaTeX,50,0,0,0,0,0,0,0  
Post Script LATEX,76,0,0,0,0,0,0,0  
LaTeX InDesign with Smart Diagram Miicrosoft Word 2013,1323,183,0,0,2,0,1,0 
Letech indesign cc,372,4,0,0,0,0,1,0    
LaTeX InDesign Crative Cloud ,751,27,0,0,0,0,1,0    
LaTeX InDesign CC,986,7,0,0,0,0,1,0 
Adobe in design cc,1435,72,1,0,1,0,0,0  
Adobe InDesign CC with LaTeX,225,11,0,0,0,0,1,0 
Membuat dokumen latex Revisi I,129,5,0,0,0,0,0,0    
Post Script LaTeX ?,51,2,0,0,0,0,1,0    
Membuat Dokumen LaTeX,3480,362,1,1,5,0,1,0  
Cover book with post scripts,77,0,1,0,0,0,0,0   
Risalah Jumat, Islam Agama Akal dan Ilmu,669,0,0,0,0,0,0,0  
Paperksmt,249,0,0,0,3,0,0,0 
Beamer color,282,0,0,0,0,0,0,0  
Doble color with beamer LaTeX,36,0,0,0,0,0,0,0  
Beameruse theme Purdue University,152,0,0,0,0,0,0,0 
Freewilly with beamerusetheme Torino.sty,399,0,0,0,0,0,0,0  
Transparansi Background with LaTeX beamer,114,0,0,0,0,0,0,0 
Chameleon, beameruse theme Torino.sty ,1150,0,0,0,1,0,0,0   
Fancy Page with LaTeX ,93,0,0,0,0,0,0,0 
Majalah  with Adobe InDesign ,42,0,0,0,0,0,0,0  
Poster with LaTeX,45,0,0,0,0,0,0,0  
Collecting Code LaTeX 2013 ,665,0,1,0,1,0,0,0   
Mengenal adobe in design cs6,3078,0,7,0,18,0,0,0    
A Beautiful Beamer LaTeX,73,0,0,0,0,0,0,0   
Coding Theory Report Final ,1001,0,1,1,10,0,0,0 
Papercoding Final,200,0,0,0,2,0,0,0 
Self Dual Codes  and Binary Golay Code Presentation ,192,5,0,0,0,0,0,0  
Bch codes final slide ,307,19,0,0,0,0,0,0   
Beautifull pink latex,65,0,0,0,0,0,0,0  
Bch codes,315,14,0,0,0,0,0,0    
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}



\section*{Theory}
    \pgfplotstabletypeset[col sep=comma,
     columns={Presentation,Views,Downloads,Favorites,Comments,Email Shares,Facebook Shares,Tweets,LinkedIn Shares},
    ]{test.csv}
\end{document}
```

But , I get error like this :

```
LaTeX Warning: Overwriting file `./test.csv'.


LaTeX Warning: Tab has been converted to Blank Space.


No file Slide_share.aux.
ABD: EveryShipout initializing macros
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\context\base\supp-pdf.mkii"
[Loading MPS to PDF converter (version 2006.09.02).]
)
Package pgfplots notification 'compat/show suggested version=true': you might b
enefit from \pgfplotsset{compat=1.11} (current compat level: 1.9).


! Package pgfplots Error: Table 'test.csv' appears to have too many columns in 
line 31: Ignoring '0'. PGFPlots found that the number of columns is larger than
 the previously determined number of columns. Please verify that every cell ent
ry is separated correctly (use braces {<cell entry>} if necessary. Also verify 
that column names are plain ASCII.). This error is not critical.

See the pgfplots package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.172     ]{test.csv}


?
```

**How to solve it ?**

Comment: Did you read the error message? It tells you ***precisely*** how to solve it. It tells you the line number, what is wrong and what to do about it. It says it is not critical, so I'm assuming you can compile anyway, but the output will likely be messed up.

Comment: @JohnKormylo Nice that it works for you, but I don't see how that is meant to help the OP ;).

Comment: @JohnKormylo , thank for your comment, but I need simple solution.

Comment: @JohnKormylo, as far as this,  I use pgfplotstable but I need edit my file one to one data.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are at least two problems. The first is that you need to tell the programme that your first column is not a floating point number, which it expects. For example:

```
\pgfplotstabletypeset[
  col sep=comma,
  columns/Presentation/.style={string type},
  columns={Presentation,Views,Downloads,Favorites,Comments,Email Shares,Facebook Shares,Tweets,LinkedIn Shares},
]{test.csv}
```

The second is that you need to think about what you are passing in the first column. For example, if the name includes a comma, that will be interpreted as a new column. To avoid this, you need to use curly brackets. For example:

```
{Minted, High Lighting Source Code},68,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
```

As the manual explains, there is nothing magical here - it is just creating tabular environments by parsing the code as you tell it. If you specify commas as the column separator, any comma *within* a column must be dealt with to avoid the parser interpreting it as a new column.

Your table is much too wide and too tall for the page, by the way.

Code which compiles but that's about all can be said for it:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable,filecontents}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.9}% supress warning

\begin{filecontents*}{test.csv}
Presentation,Views,Downloads,Favorites,Comments,Email Shares,Facebook Shares,Tweets,LinkedIn Shares
Biber,3,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
Matlab Prettifier Package,68,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
LaTeX3,173,1,0,0,0,0,0,0
PythonTeX,84,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
PerlTeX,131,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
Matplotlib ,37,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
SciPy,68,0,1,0,0,0,0,0
PythonTeX Quick Start,22,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
Introduction to PythonTeX,34,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
IPython,30,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
Matplotlib Introduction ,30,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
Galeri PythonTeX,54,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
IPython : Operasi Dasar di Sympy,30,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
Introduction to IPython ,22,1,0,0,0,0,0,0
Introduction to NumPy,23,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
Road to PythonTeX ,72,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
PythonTeX dan Sympy kolaborasi ,28,3,0,0,0,0,0,0
Andreas Linz Beamer ,33,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
Menyisipkan teks Arab ke LaTeX,21,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
Xelatex \& Japanese,17,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
Korean xelatex,27,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
Wordlike,19,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
LaTeX    Notasi Matematika ,68,10,0,0,0,0,0,0
MusicTEX " Simpony LATEX dalam Musik " ,255,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
Membuat Dokumen LaTeX3,23,1,0,0,0,0,0,0
Membuat Dokumen Beamer LaTeX,63,1,0,0,0,0,0,0
Membuat Dokumen LaTeX ,146,4,0,0,0,0,0,0
Beamer   Media Presentasi LaTeX,141,15,0,0,0,0,0,0
Membuat Dokumen LaTeX,273,5,0,0,0,0,3,0
Beamer Theme Glugor,49,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
{Minted, High Lighting Source Code},68,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
Penggunaan dua bahasa dalam dokumen LATEX,142,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
Solusi kesalahan ketika penggantian bahasa,138,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
Ping! LaTeX ,215,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
Membuat Dokumen LaTeX edisi 13,313,6,0,0,0,0,0,0
{Beamer, Media Presentasi LaTeX},216,5,0,0,0,0,0,0
Membuat dokumen la tex edisi 12,405,2,0,0,0,0,5,0
Membuat Dokumen LaTeX  Eleventh Edition,454,18,2,0,0,0,0,0
Presentasi Beamer : Dark Themes,228,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
{Simpleslides, Media Presentasi ConTeXt },83,3,0,0,0,0,0,0
Laporan Metode Statistikia II,236,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
Con text Untuk Pemula,48,1,0,0,0,0,0,0
My Talking Custom and Tools ,116,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
Farm Frenzy ,299,1,0,0,0,0,0,0
LaTeX 3 Paper,73,1,0,0,0,0,0,0
R -Sweave/ Sweave For Statistical Programming at LaTeX ,165,5,0,0,0,0,0,0
LaTeX Cheat Sheet,194,9,0,0,0,0,0,0
LaTeX Cheat Sheet ,77,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
{PlainTeX, A Virgin TeX :)},129,2,0,0,0,0,0,0
Beamer atau .PpT,288,11,0,0,0,0,0,0
Xelatex,142,5,0,0,0,0,0,0
Powerdot slide,276,25,0,0,0,0,0,0
Kaligrafi and math font,328,2,0,0,0,0,0,0
Utopia regular with math design,225,1,0,0,0,0,0,0
Tx fonts,195,1,0,0,0,0,0,0
Times,203,1,0,0,0,0,0,0
Px fonts,189,1,0,0,0,0,0,0
Palatino,209,1,0,0,0,0,0,0
New century school book,201,1,0,0,0,0,0,0
Lx font,21,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
Latin modern,25,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
Kurier light condensed,24,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
Kurier light,18,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
Kurier condensed,13,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
Kurier condensed,21,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
Kurier,203,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
Kurier,50,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
Kerkis,42,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
Kp sans serif,38,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
Iwona light condensed,15,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
Iwona light,16,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
Iwona condensed,27,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
Iwona,15,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
Gfs neohellenic,19,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
Gfs artemisia with,22,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
Gfs artemisia,22,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
Computer modern light,18,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
Computer modern,12,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
Computer concrete,16,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
Charter bt,13,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
Charter bt,20,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
Boisik,21,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
Arev,24,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
Antykwa toruÅ„ska light,9,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
Antykwa toruÅ„ska condensed light,18,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
Antykwa toruÅ„ska condensed,16,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
Antykwa toruÅ„ska,23,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
Chap16 scr,158,3,0,0,0,0,0,0
Chap15 scr,36,2,0,0,0,0,0,0
Chap14 scr,56,1,0,0,0,0,0,0
Chap12 scr,68,3,0,0,0,0,0,0
Chap11 scr,53,2,0,0,0,0,0,0
Chap10 scr,41,2,0,0,0,0,0,0
Chap09 scr,240,1,0,0,0,0,0,0
Chap08 scr,51,2,0,0,0,0,0,0
Chap07 scr,56,1,0,0,0,0,0,0
Chap06 scr,48,1,0,0,0,0,0,0
Chap05 scr,36,1,0,0,0,0,0,0
Chap04 scr,33,1,0,0,0,0,0,0
Chap03 scr,56,1,0,0,0,0,0,0
Chap02 scr,88,1,0,0,0,0,0,0
Chap01 scr,401,2,0,0,0,0,0,0
Chap17 scr,140,1,0,0,0,0,0,0
Chap13 scr,66,4,0,0,0,0,0,0
Fancy Beamer :),78,0,0,0,0,0,1,0
Vector in ConTeXt ,55,0,0,0,0,0,1,0
Synonyms in ConTeXt,47,0,0,0,0,0,1,0
Special character in ConTeXt ,63,0,0,0,0,0,1,0
Powerdot LaTeX,324,1,0,0,0,0,1,0
Outlinde text in ConTeXt,49,0,0,0,0,0,1,0
MetaPost in LaTeX,137,3,0,0,0,0,1,0
Math in ConTeXt ,142,4,0,0,0,0,1,0
Math basic in ConTeXt,124,1,0,0,0,0,1,0
Math align in ConTeXt ,64,0,0,0,0,0,1,0
Itemize in ConTeXt,459,0,0,0,0,0,1,0
Definitions in ConTeXt,153,0,0,0,0,0,1,0
Columns in  ConTeXt ,61,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
Combining Statistical Programming with LaTeX,29,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
Combining Statistical Programming with LaTeX,38,2,0,0,0,0,0,0
Beamer Presentation,459,11,0,2,0,0,1,0
Pengantar la tex,246,5,0,0,0,0,1,0
LaTeX InDesign Creative Cloud with PGF/ TikZ,1512,24,0,0,0,0,1,0
Post Script LaTeX,50,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
Post Script LATEX,76,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
LaTeX InDesign with Smart Diagram Miicrosoft Word 2013,1323,183,0,0,2,0,1,0
Letech indesign cc,372,4,0,0,0,0,1,0
LaTeX InDesign Crative Cloud ,751,27,0,0,0,0,1,0
LaTeX InDesign CC,986,7,0,0,0,0,1,0
Adobe in design cc,1435,72,1,0,1,0,0,0
Adobe InDesign CC with LaTeX,225,11,0,0,0,0,1,0
Membuat dokumen latex Revisi I,129,5,0,0,0,0,0,0
Post Script LaTeX ?,51,2,0,0,0,0,1,0
Membuat Dokumen LaTeX,3480,362,1,1,5,0,1,0
Cover book with post scripts,77,0,1,0,0,0,0,0
{Risalah Jumat, Islam Agama Akal dan Ilmu},669,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
Paperksmt,249,0,0,0,3,0,0,0
Beamer color,282,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
Doble color with beamer LaTeX,36,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
Beameruse theme Purdue University,152,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
Freewilly with beamerusetheme Torino.sty,399,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
Transparansi Background with LaTeX beamer,114,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
{Chameleon, beameruse theme Torino.sty },1150,0,0,0,1,0,0,0
Fancy Page with LaTeX ,93,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
Majalah  with Adobe InDesign ,42,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
Poster with LaTeX,45,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
Collecting Code LaTeX 2013 ,665,0,1,0,1,0,0,0
Mengenal adobe in design cs6,3078,0,7,0,18,0,0,0
A Beautiful Beamer LaTeX,73,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
Coding Theory Report Final ,1001,0,1,1,10,0,0,0
Papercoding Final,200,0,0,0,2,0,0,0
Self Dual Codes  and Binary Golay Code Presentation ,192,5,0,0,0,0,0,0
Bch codes final slide ,307,19,0,0,0,0,0,0
Beautifull pink latex,65,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
Bch codes,315,14,0,0,0,0,0,0
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}
```

## EDIT

Next? Start with page 21 of the manual which explains how to customise the table environment. For example (quoting from the manual verbatim):

```
% replicate column names on top of every page of a multi-page table:
\pgfplotstableset{
row sep=\\,
begin table=\begin{longtable},
end table=\end{longtable},
every head row/.append style={after row=\endhead},
}
```

Comment: I tried your answer , but How to make breaklines to next page and edit my table ?

Comment: @Hirwanto That's a different question. I suggest taking a look at the documentation for the package. (I've never used it before.) I don't understand what you mean by how to edit it - you just edit it, as you like. But you have to decide what to do about the width. You can use a different environment to break lengthwise, but the width requires you to think about how you are presenting the data.

Comment: @Hirwanto I've added a pointer to the relevant part of the documentation, which explains how to use `longtable` for long tables. But how to format the columns to fit the width is something you have to decide in light of the information you are presenting.

Comment: Ok, I reading pgfplotstable manual :)